# How do I remove this plastic fitting connected under my kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing

I am trying to replace my kitchen faucet which is leaking at the base. So far I am struggling to remove the leaky faucet. There is a black and white plastic connection piece that I have been unsuccessful at removing. Does anyone know how to remove this thing?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Squeeze those two ends together and push in... The other end should come out and you might need a screwdriver to pry it out a little more. To reinstall it, put the connector back on the pipe and push the flat white side back in until it snaps in place.